# How to read a file lines between two bytes position

Tags: c

I am currently reading a file lines from an offset position(the quarter of the file) till the end :

```
struct stat st;
stat("file.txt", &st);
int fileSize = st.st_size
int minOffset = fileSize/4;
FILE* file_ptr = fopen("file.txt", "r");
fseek(file_ptr, minOffset, SEEK_SET);

int lineLength = 1000;
char * line; 
line = malloc(lineLength);

while (read = getline(&line, &lineLength, file_ptr) != -1) {
   printf("%s", line);
}
```

But what I need is to **read all lines between two bytes position** in the file. As Olaf stated in the comments, **I also have the issue that my offset is not necesseraly at line boundary.**

For exemple, this could be the maxOffset that I would like to read :

```
int maxOffset = fileSize / 2;
```

**I want to read from the line where the minOffset position is to the line before the maxOffset position.**

The file consists of words(one by line) that always have a length that is  smaller then 1000 :

```
AA
AAS
ABACA
ABACAS
ABACOST
ABACOSTS
ABACULE
ABACULES
ABAISSA
ABAISSABLE
ABAISSABLES
ABAISSAI
ABAISSAIENT
ABAISSAIS
ABAISSAIT
ABAISSAMES
ABAISSANT
ABAISSANTE
ABAISSANTES
ABAISSANTS
ABAISSAS
ABAISSASSE
ABAISSASSENT
ABAISSASSES
ABAISSASSIEZ
ABAISSASSIONS
ABAISSAT
ABAISSATES 
....
```

How can I read a file lines beetween two bytes position ?

Comment: Do yu want to read _lines_ or just the whole block? For the first: How do you ensure both positions are at line-boundaries? And provide a [mcve]. `getline` is no standard function.

Comment: Use `@name` to address a comment!

Comment: A quarter of a **text** file is not necessarily at a line-boundary. So that conclusion is wrong - unless you have not given all information.

Comment: Also do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @Olaf I edited my answer is this better now ?

Comment: Still information missing. Anyway, that looks like a bad aproach. In general, you should have one read thread which reads the file and passes the data to worker threads. Having four threads reading a file will slow down reading on a HDD significantly and not increase speed **at best** on a SSD. How does the file look like (just give the necessary information)? Can you guarantee constant line-length? What if there is a fault in the file?

Comment: How does that change the issues I listed?

Comment: @Olaf I improved my question thankyou for your advice again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find the byte position of the start of a line at the 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4 points. To do that:

- `fseek` to the approximate position (e.g `fseek(filesize/4)`)
- call `fgets` to read up to the next newline
- call `ftell` to determine the offset

The offset returned is the end of one quarter and the beginning of the next.

To read one quarter of the file:

- `fseek` to the beginning of the quarter
- call `fgets` to read a line
- call `ftell` to see if you've reached the end of the quarter

Answer (score 2):

You want function [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/):

```
int byteStart = 100;
int byteEnd   = 200;
line = malloc(byteEnd-byteStart);            // Allocate enough space for your data.
fseek(file_ptr, byteStart, SEEK_SET);        // Go to your starting point
fread(line, 1, byteEnd-byteStart, file_ptr); // Read until your ending point.
```

Comment: I think OP really want to read _lines_, not just a binary block.